# Dictionary not filled with Values when calling from another class

Tags: c#, console

So i am trying to call a dctionary I have from another class.
I have 2 classes, `Subreddit` and `Posts`. I need a sortedset of `Posts` in the `Subreddit` class so i can query and find which id's match and find what posts belong to which subreddit. Here is my declaration of the Post dictionary I am trying to use:

```
public static Dictionary<uint, Post> sortedPostDictionary = new Dictionary<uint, Post>();
```

In the `Post` class this dictionary gets sorted and is filled with values just fine. Once I call it in the `Subreddit` class:

```
public void buildSubPosts()
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Post> data in Post.sortedPostDictionary)
    {
        subPosts.Add(new Post(data.Key, data.Value.AuthorID, data.Value.UpVotes,
            data.Value.DownVotes, data.Value.Weight, data.Value.SubHome,
            data.Value.PostTitle, data.Value.PostContent, data.Value.TimeStamp,
            data.Value.Score));
    }
}
```

The `foreach` loop wont even loop over the dictionary since it is empty. I tried making the Dictionary static and public but that hasnt worked. Can anyone help me fix my issue?

Here is the `SortedSet` declaration I am trying to place values in:

```
 public static SortedSet<Post> subPosts = new SortedSet<Post>();

public void sortDictionary()
{
    buildDateTime();
    ArrayList sortedPosts = new ArrayList();

    foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Post> value in postDictionary)
    {
        sortedPosts.Add(value.Value.postTitle);
    }

    sortedPosts.Sort();

    foreach (var value in sortedPosts)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<uint, Post> key in postDictionary)
        {
            if (value.ToString() == key.Value.postTitle.ToString())
            {
                Post tempData = new Post
                {
                    postID = key.Key,
                    authorID = key.Value.authorID,
                    postTitle = key.Value.postTitle,
                    postContent = key.Value.PostContent,
                    subHome = key.Value.subHome,
                    upVotes = key.Value.upVotes,
                    downVotes = key.Value.downVotes,
                    weight = key.Value.weight,
                    year = key.Value.year,
                    score = Score,
                    month = key.Value.month,
                    day = key.Value.day,
                    hour = key.Value.hour,
                    minute = key.Value.minute,
                    millisecond = key.Value.millisecond,
                    timeStamp = key.Value.timeStamp,
                };

                sortedPostDictionary.Add(tempData.postID, tempData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the dictionary getting filled in the `Posts` class which is called in `Main` before the user can decide what choice they want to make:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Questions:
    //SortedSet Enumeration
    string userInput = "";
    User userObj = new User();
    userObj.readData();

    //Read sub data
    Subreddit subObj = new Subreddit();
    subObj.readData();
    subObj.buildSubPosts();
    Subreddit.subEnum subEnumObj = new Subreddit.subEnum();

    //Read post data
    Post postObj = new Post();
    postObj.readData();
    Comment commentOBJ = new Comment();
    commentOBJ.readData();
}
```

Comment: Based on the code you provided here it is impossible to say for sure why this snippet doesn't work. We need an [mcve] to help you better otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: @rene I'm not really sure what else to include since the dictionary has the values I need and posting the code for inserting values into the Dictionary doesnt seem necessary

Comment: @HarryFischer *"he foreach loop wont even loop over the dictionary since it is empty"* -- that's a quote from your question. Are you saying that the values you need are no values, and that an empty dictionary is what you want? Or are you saying that the dictionary *does not have the values you need*? There are two possibilities here: Either there are two different dictionaries, one full and one empty, where you think there is only one; or else it's the same dictionary, and you're adding stuff to it and then clearing it.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Im saying that the dictionary is read into and contains values when the program executes. When I call it from the Subreddit class it wont execute the foreach since it is empty when calling from that class

Comment: @HarryFischer If "the dictionary" is full, and then empty, either you're replacing it, or clearing it, or you've got two unrelated pieces of code looking at two unrelated dictionaries. Please show us enough code to illustrate which of those cases is happening. There *is absolutely no case, ever* where the same dictionary is both full and empty, depending on who's looking at it. Maybe you've got two instances of whatever `Post` is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett added more code to hopefully clear it up. I am not clearing or replacing values once the values are in the sortedPostDicitonary they stay there. For some reason when calling from the other class it wont show the values that should be contain in the dictionary

Comment: @HarryFischer What I really need here is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which demonstrates the issue you're having. What you've given me is two unrelated fragments more or less arbitrarily chopped out of your application. My above explanation is correct; [I've done this before](https://stackoverflow.com/users/424129/ed-plunkett?tab=answers). Unfortunately, I don't have enough of your code to identify how you're getting your hands on the wrong dictionary. If you supply it, I'll show you where the second dictionary is introduced.

Comment: your previous code kind of worked if I fantasized about the missing bits: https://ideone.com/544ilf but I don't start that same exercise with what is currently presented. Too much assumptions needed ...

Comment: What's `Post`? `public Post Post => new Post();`?

Comment: Please add code for method `Subreddit.readData()` and property `Subreddit.Post`.